# Axios and FW/1 unable to use headers (CORS error)

Tags: vue.js, coldfusion, cors, axios, fw1

I am unable to use headers with my axios request

This works

**App.vue**

```
axios
    .get(Config.BASEURL + 'pref/footer', { })
    .then(response => (this.footer = response.data))
```

This does not

**App.vue**

```
axios
    .get(Config.BASEURL + 'pref/footer', { crossDomain: true, headers: {"Authorization":1}})
    .then(response => (this.footer = response.data))
```

My end point looks like this

**application.cfc**

```
...
variables.framework.routes  = [
    // Rest
    { "$GET/rest/carousel"                  = "rest/carousel"                       },
    { "$PUT/rest/contactus"                 = "rest/contactus"                      },
    { "$POST/rest/login"                    = "restLogin/loginPOST"                 },
    { "$GET/rest/message"                   = "rest/message"                        },
    { "$GET/rest/page/:id"                  = "rest/page/slug/:id"                  },
    { "$GET/rest/page"                      = "rest/page"                           },
    { "$GET/rest/pref/:id"                  = "rest/pref/slug/:id"                  },
...
```

I get an error message that looks like this:

[image]

In the `App.vue`, I can't figure out what to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of the problem is not on the client side. It is on the Server side. In particular it is in FW/1 which is a part of the ColdFusion. The magic word is `preflight response`. When Axois does it get request, it actually does an `OPTIONS` before `GET`. So what you have to do is convince FW\1 to respond to `OPTIONS` the long way is the explicitly add `OPTIONS` to the `variables.framework.routes`, but there is a much simpler way to do this. Just add the following to the config.

**application.cfc**

```
variables.framework =   {
    ...
    preflightOptions = true,
    ...
    };
```